# NFS Volume service in PCF

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to connect to existing NAS mounted path from PCF application. To achieve this, I have a NFS service instance in PCF and am able to create the service , bind the service to the application and execute the application.

i am able to view files from  the  NAS mounted path by doing SSH on the  PCF application  as suggested by the trouble shooting link (please provide the link here) But when i am trying to access the source code (sample html file) from mounted path via application I am unable to access due to path not being resolved properly though I am using the /nfs/volume1 as prefix before the file name.

manifest.yml

```
applications:
- name: samplw
  memory: 64M
  path: /nfs/volume1/
```

abc.jpg file available in the volume server

When i try to access that end point URL that image should get load, But the image was not loading

Comment: When am trying to access the abc.jpg image available at the Volume server image not getting loaded..

Comment: How are you pushing your application? What is the full `cf push` command & output? Also, you have `path: /nfs/volume1` in your application manifest.yml file. What do you mean by that? That is telling the client what files to push, so it must exist locally & has no impact on what happens server side. Does that exist locally? Lastly, include how you are creating and binding the service, with sensitive data masked out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel Thanks for your response.                                                                                           I am pushing Application as sample with cf push command like below                      cf push sample -b php_buildpack -p sample                                                             Application was pushed successfully and up and running also. In my application contains sample html page form that page am trying to load the image available at mounted path..

Comment: /nfs/volume1   path is nothing but while we are binding the nfs service to the application we have given the mounted path like /nfs/volume1  so that what are file avaliable in the server mounted path like /abc/source/ in x.x.x.x IP are copied to that local path to the /nfs/volume1 and we validate the also while we dig into ssh cell and checked files are avilable in the local mounted path as /nfs/volume1 and source available in that path also

Comment: Creating the nfs service like below                                                                             cf create-service nfs Existing nfs_service -c config.json    and json file likes below  {  
   "share":"x.x.x.x.com/abc/source"
}

Comment: Binding that service to the application likes below                                                     cf bind-service sample nfs_service -c nfs.json   and json file likes below                       {"uid":"1000","gid":"1000","mount":"/nfs/volume1","readonly":true}

Comment: OK, first. Because you're using `cf push -p sample ...` the `-p` is overriding the path to push (i.e. where the cf cli finds your local app bits) and `path: /nfs/volume1` in your manifest.yml snippet is not being used. That is likely just causing confusion and I would suggest removing it.

Comment: Second, are you trying to serve files directly off the NFS? For example, you're pushing an app and what you push contains your source code, but static resources are not being pushed and are coming from NFS? Just trying to understand how you are using the NFS mount here.

Comment: Thanks Daniel..For the first point we have tried without -p option also while pushing the application..

Comment: For second point yes we are having the static resources in the NFS volume path(/nfs/volume1) and from the PCF application we are trying to access it from  the static file  index.html like /nfs/volume1/novedades.jpg  and we tried another option also like directly novedades.jpg because already mounted path is binde to the application both oprtions are not working

Comment: How are you getting the file from `/nfs/volume1` to the app director? The PHP buildpack is going to set the document root of HTTPD to `/home/vcap/app/htdocs`, so it's only going to serve up files under that directory root. You can serve up files form elsewhere but it requires some adjustments to the default HTTPD configuration used by the PHP buildpack. Is that what you're trying to figure out here?

Comment: Yes we are trying with httpd configuration file also by setting the server name as hostname and Doccumeroot as /nfs/volume1 but while pushing the application itself we are getting the error and application getting crashed because /nfs/volume1 path it's expecting from our app as per my understand.

Comment: While binding nfs service itself we have given the mounted path as /nsf/volume1 so I don't think so Do we have to set Documentroot as nfs/volume1 And we validated also that inside ssh cell of that application staic files are copied from NAS mounted path to local mounted path /nfs/volume1

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to do this, here's two that should work.

1. The simplest way would be to add a `.profile` script to the root of your application. This is a script which runs before your app starts. In that, you could copy files from `/nfs/volume1` to `/home/vcap/app/htdocs/`, which is the docroot configured by the buildpack. Any files you copy into that directory will be served up by Apache Web Server.

   I would only do this if you have a small amount of files on the server, so that they copy quickly (less than 10s). Otherwise you'll end up waiting for a while every time your app has to start, which is not efficient. You could also get to the point where it causes your app to timeout and fail to start, if the copy is slow enough. That said, this will give you the absolute best performance. When you serve directly from NFS, it will be slower.
2. If you want to serve directly from NFS, my suggestion would be to keep the docroot where it is by default and add an Alias directive to map some path under your app to the files on NFS. For example, you could add an alias to map `/static`/ to `/nfs/volume1`, and all your files under `/nfs/volume1` would be served up when accessing `/static/...` with the same path.

   This is the additional config you'd need to add to the default used by the buildpack is...

   ```
   LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
   Alias /static /nfs/volume1
   <Directory "/nfs/volume1">
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```

   It would need to go under your app in `.bp-config/httpd/extra/httpd-modules.conf` (or some other config file that the buildpack uses, [there are a few](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/defaults/config/httpd/extra/)).

   There's a full example of this you can see here -> https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/php-nfs-demo

   If all you're doing is serving up static files, you might be able to set the alias to `/` or you could try altering the `DocumentRoot`. That gets set [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/defaults/config/httpd/httpd.conf#L5) but I don't recall if you can actually override that file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response..I have implemented your 2nd approch with alias and working as expected.. I really appreciated your support..Thank you so much..

Comment: We are unable to implement ScriptAlias to load CGI script in Pivotal using PHP build pack. The below command used in httpd.conf file

Comment: Command is ScriptAlias /static  /script/samplecgi as well added Directory tag with Require all granted access but won't work . We are getting file not found script/samplecgi/test.cgi while accessing the application like routename/static/test.cgi in pcf

Comment: We have script/samplecgi folder also available in our app

Comment: It's unlikely that the path `/script/samplecgi` exists, as you wouldn't be able to write to that location as the vcap user. You want `ScriptAlias` to point to the location of your CGI scripts. The usual example is `ScriptAlias "/cgi-bin/" "${HOME}/htdocs/cgi-bin/"`, which exposes `http://example.com/cgi-bin/my-script.cgi` to a script located under your app root at `htdocs/cgi-bin/my-script.cgi`. Try adjusting the second argument to ScriptAlias which is the path on disk to the folder with your CGI scripts. If you need more help, start a new question.